# Unable to get all children node's text using XPath Selector in Scrapy

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I am scraping this URL https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/073532963X and it has `//*[@id="ddmDeliveryMessage"]` XPath element. (Please select Australia as Delivery Address)

That element has HTML like this

`<div id="ddmDeliveryMessage" class="a-section a-spacing-mini">
     <span class="a-text-bold">Estimated delivery</span> 18 Oct.4 Nov. when you choose <span class="a-text-bold">Standard Delivery</span> at checkout. <a href="">Details</a>
            </div>`

I have tried `//*[@id="ddmDeliveryMessage"]/text()` but it gives empty results

I have tried `//*[@id="ddmDeliveryMessage"]//text()` it also gives empty results

Also tried `Selector(response).css('div[id=ddmDeliveryMessage]::text').extract()[0]` but gives empty response.

Can someone tell me a selector to get all text inside `ddmDeliveryMessage` DIV?

NOTE:

`//*[@id="ddmDeliveryMessage"]` gives me whole HTML.

Comment: That's a broader problem - `//*[@id="ddmDeliveryMessage"]` would also give you an empty result.

Comment: @alecxe nahhh. it gives me HTML .. it does not give me empty result

Comment: Ah, I see, the request needed a user-agent. Thanks.

Comment: I can give you whole spider code if you say. please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Your `..//text()` option actually worked for me when I made a request via Scrapy Shell providing the *User-Agent header*:

```
$ scrapy shell https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/073532963X -s USER_AGENT='Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36'
In [1]: ' '.join(item.strip() for item in response.xpath('//*[@id="ddmDeliveryMessage"]//text()').extract()).strip()
Out[1]: u'Estimated delivery 18 Oct.\xa0-\xa04 Nov. when you choose Standard Delivery at checkout. Details'
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting HTML and then stripping HTML Tags using RegEx.

```
delivery = Selector(response).xpath('//*[@id="ddmDeliveryMessage"]').extract()[0]
delivery = self.rx.sub(' ', re.sub(r'<[^>]*?>', '', delivery).replace("\n","")).strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the correct XPATH is `//*[@id="ddmDeliveryMessage"]/span/text()`